# Configure the root path of a RequestMapping to be reusable in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, request-mapping

I'd like to centralize the root path of some of our endpoints in order to avoid having to write every url for the different endpoints.

I have something similar to this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = {"/api/en/myproject", "/api/de/myproject"})
public ResponseEntity<?> myProject() {
    ...
}
    
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = {"/api/en/myproject/subproject", "/api/de/myproject/subproject"})
public ResponseEntity<?> mySubProject() {
    ...
}
```

I've tried creating a static string[] but the compiler doesn't allow non-constant attributes there.

What I'd like to have is, but I am not sure if a workaround could be achieved:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = {getProjectPath()})
public ResponseEntity<?> myProject() {
    ...
}
    
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = {getSubprojectPath()})
public ResponseEntity<?> mySubProject() {
    ...
}
```

That way I could append `/subproject` to the first array of strings and if some path changes in the future I only need to look at one place.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It is possible to explictly manage your mappings in code, not via annotation. This would allow to use more dynamic request mappings. See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-requestmapping.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-registration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to define request mapping value in application properties file and updated it on runtime or directly in file as you want:

```
@RequestMapping("/${project.path}")
public ResponseEntity<?> myProject() {
  //...
}

@RequestMapping("/${subProject.path}")
public ResponseEntity<?> mySubProject() {
  //...
}
```

in application.properties file:

```
project.path=/project/path
subProject.path=subProject/path
```

With this, you can also set these properties using env variables if you want.

Hope it's could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case you can use parametrized URL and just ignore `language` parameter

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/{lang}/myproject")
public ResponseEntity<?> myProject(@PathVariable("lang") String language) {
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/{lang}/myproject/subproject")
public ResponseEntity<?> mySubProject(@PathVariable("lang") String language) {
    ...
}
```

P.S. `@RestController` should be used for classes only, not for methods